# Is there an R function that can be used to group numbers into discreet percentage "buckets"?

Tags: r

I split a biological sample into multiple "tiles" using a program called QuPath and I'm using R to parse the data. I was hoping to divide the tiles into different buckets based on the percentage of the tile is taken up by stroma (0-10%, 10-20%, etc.). Ideally, I'd like something like the below table, but anything where I can get counts of the number of tiles that fall into the percentage "buckets" will be just fine.

| Tile | Percent Stroma | Percent Stroma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tile 1 | 5% | 0-10 |
| Tile 2 | 15% | 10-20 |
| Tile 3 | 9% | 0-10 |
| Tile 4 | 45% | 40-50 |
| Tile 5 | 61% | 60-70 |
| Tile 6 | 42% | 40-50 |
| Tile 7 | 55% | 50-60 |

I've done something like this before with a simple ifelse function, but I'm very new to R and wanted to know if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: You'll need to remove the percent signs and convert them to numeric to work with them, and then the `cut` function is your friend. See the two linked duplicates for those two steps.

Comment: If you're using `library(dplyr)` and `library(readr)` you can do something like `your_data %>% mutate(stroma_numeric = parse_number(Percent_Stroma), stroma_bucket = cut(stroma_numeric, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), include.lowest = TRUE))`.